# MySql.Data.Entity provide encode for Cyrillic

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have Asp MVC solution with Linq to MySql.

In table, text field varchar(120) (In DB property Collaction UFT8 default) is present.

In EDMX this property Unicode = false for this field.

But via EntityObject I can't save Cyrillic values to this field it always = ????
Direct query to database save values correctly.
Why it happens ?

Comment: What client are you using?  How are you typing Cyrillic?  `SELECT col, HEX(col) ... ` so we can see what did get inserted.  If it got entered correctly, you will see DxxxDxxxDxxx... for the hex of the Cyrillic characters.  If you see C39xxxxx, I will predict "double encoding".  If neither, then the INSERT was broken.

Answer (score 0):

I added **Charset=utf8** to web config, connection string and it is working now